# JOGL objects "Disappearing" when moving around a scene

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to implement a basic physics engine in Java and I'm using the JOGL bindings so I can visualize the results. I can create and rotate shapes easily enough, but have run into problems whilst manipulating the viewport and whilst moving the shapes.

I don't think a clipping issue - I've tried using the gluPerspective method with a massive range (0.0001f - 10000f) with no success. When I move the camera further away from my objects or move the objects themselves, they disappear.

Tutorials about JOGL are few and far between and many also use different versions of OpenGL, so I turn to the only friend I have left: the wonderful users of stack overflow. :)

Flattery aside, the code follows:

```
public class JoglEventListener implements GLEventListener, KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
// keep pointer to associated canvas so we can refresh the screen (equivalent to glutPostRedisplay())     
public GLCanvas canvas;
public Particle triforce;
public float x;

// constructor
public JoglEventListener(GLCanvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    update();
    render(drawable);
}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    triforce = new Particle();
    x = 0;
}

private void update() {
    triforce.integrate(0.0001);
    x = x + 0.25f;
}

 private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    GLU glu = new GLU();

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);        
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    //gl.glFrustum (.5f, -.5f, -.5f * 1080, .5f * 960, 1.f, 500.f);
    glu.gluPerspective(0, 1, 0.1f, 100f);        


    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glHint(GL2.GL_CLIP_VOLUME_CLIPPING_HINT_EXT,GL2.GL_FASTEST);
    glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, -10, 0, 1, 0);        
    //gl.glRotatef(90, 0f , 1f , 0f );
    //Draw some scale lines
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glColor3f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i += 1)
    {
        gl.glVertex3f(-5.0f, 0.0f, i + 0.5f);
        gl.glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, i + 0.5f);
    }
    gl.glEnd();

    //gl.glRotatef(x, 1f , 1f , 1f );         

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslated(triforce.position.x, triforce.position.y, triforce.position.z);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);                       
    gl.glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);                       
    gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, -2);
    gl.glColor3f(0f, 1f, 0f);                       
    gl.glVertex3d(0, 0.25d, -2);                
    gl.glColor3f(0f, 0f, 1f);                       
    gl.glVertex3d(0.25d, 0, -2);
    gl.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 0f);                       
    gl.glVertex3d(0.25d, 0.25d, -2.25d);
    gl.glEnd();                                       
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glFlush();
}
```

// (empty overridden methods omitted)

```
public Particle () {
    setMass(200d);
    velocity = new Vector3(0d, 30d, 40d);
    acceleration = new Vector3(0d, -20d, 0d);
    position = new Vector3(0d, 0d, 0d);
    damping = 0.99d;
}

public void integrate (double duration) {
    if (inverseMass <= 0.0d) {
        return;
    }
    assert (duration > 0.0);
    position.addScaledVector(velocity, duration);
    Vector3 resultingAcc = new Vector3(acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z);
    velocity.addScaledVector(resultingAcc, duration);
    velocity.multEquals(Math.pow(damping, duration));
    //clearAccumulator();
}

public void setMass(double mass)
{
    assert(mass != 0);
    inverseMass = (1.0d)/mass;
}
```

Before movement / starting position:

[image: Before]

The shape drifts upward and is obscured from the right and top, becoming invisible:

[image: During]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Without looking at your code: What do you mean by disappearing? Do they pop on and off in a certain distance? Are they cut off until not being seen anymore? Maybe you can provide a picture or even video?

Comment: Have you tried making `update` do nothing to make sure its not a physics bug?

Comment: @toto - Yes, I've tried removing this step. The strange thing is that the objects seem to only be visible in a small area around 0,0,0 - by that I mean that when the camera or the objects move a small distance away they disappear. This suggests something other than the physics is going wrong...

Comment: @Nobody - just tried to post images but was defeating by the spam blocking! I need to work on my reputation :)

In terms of how they disappear, the items gradually float upward (as per the physics code) and then disappear incrementally at an angle, like they are going behind a black curtain hanging at 45 degrees. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Just to check as I don't see you use it here: Did you switch the matrix mode when setting up the projection matrix? The behaviour you describe sounds like clipping to me although some pics would be nice. You could try using some hoster like imageshack and then post the link here?

Comment: @Nobody I've seen some tutorials that manipulate the matrix stack between Projection & Modelview, but can't seem to get this to work with JOGL; when I call "gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);" I get a compile time error (cannot find symbol). I'll add pics to the main story thru image shack shortly.

Comment: @Nobody - I've worked out how to use the glMatrixMode function now - you call it with the parameter GL2.GL_PROJECTION. Still no improvement at present.

Comment: So did you: Set Projection Matrixmode, set gluPerspective or whatever projection you want and then set the matrix mode to `GL_MODELVIEW` and make all scene AND camera transformations you need? Btw from what I see on the Images it clearly seems to be a clipping issue. Did you define any additional clipping planes?

Comment: Maybe you want to try out this: `glHint(GL_CLIP_VOLUME_CLIPPING_HINT_EXT,GL_FASTEST);` to disable viewingvolume clipping, but it relies on an extension that might not be available to you.

Comment: I haven't added any extra clipping planes. I've updated my .render() loop with my current code - in it I follow the MatrixMode as per your comment and as per the red book. Still no improvement. glHint compiles but also seems to not have an effect.

I agree that it looks like textbook clipping, but I can't for the life of me find out how it's happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was never able to track down the issue, and started again from scratch. I didn't run into any further clipping issues on my new build.

My best guess as to my initial failure is an improperly used glHint or glClear call, or perhaps some problem with the version of JOGL I was referencing.

Comment: If you use JOGL 2.3.2 which is currently (April 2017) the latest version, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The massive view range can be a problem. The coordinates of the objects are only so precise, and with a huge view range, things that should be near each other are determined to be at the same point. This can cause an object that should be in front of another to disappear behind it. Try using a smaller view range.

Comment: Thanks - I have experimented with many different ranges, all to no avail (in fact, in the above code I have commented this command out).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Objects disappearing, while some stay in the scene. After removing:

```
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

everything was working just fine ! Of course this is JOGL code, in C, the command would be without all those objects. Just to make this answer clear for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In the `render` function, change the value of last parameter of `gluPerspective` from 100f to 1000f. It will solve your problem.

```
gl.gluPerspective(0, 1, 0.1f, 100f);
```

to

```
gl.gluPerspective(0, 1, 0.1f, 500f);
```

And I think in your code you have done a mistake in the above line writing `glu.gluperspective`

I think it is `gl.gluPerspective`.